# How to always show the date of the 2nd in every month?

Tags: reporting-services

I need ssrs code that would always show me the date of the 2nd for last month. So 3/2/2019 .

I understand that this code below will always show me the 1st of last month, but how to modify to show the 2nd??

=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for simply changing the last 1 to a 2.

```
=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),2))
```